# Why do I get the Undefined Index Error?

Tags: php, database, authentication, undefined-index

I am making a simple login form that saves to a database using MYSQL. I used a tutorial and at the end when I tested it I got an error saying

```
'Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\wamp\www\database_test\login.php on line 7'
```

Don't know what this means and after searching the internet still can't figure it out. Here is my code. Please help. Thanks!

```
 <?php

     session_name('MyLogin');
     session_start();
     session_destroy();

     if ($_GET['login'] == "failed") {    //<------This is line 7//
         print $_GET['cause'];
     }

 ?>
 <html>
     <body>
         <form name='login_form' method='post' action='log.php?action=login'>
             Login: <input type='text' name='user'><br />
             Password: <input type='password' name='pwd'><br />
             <input type='submit'>
         </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

I basically copied this from a tutorial at

http://www.howtodothings.com/computers-internet/how-to-make-a-login-system-for-your-website

Comment: "I basically copied this from a tutorial at" --- being a programmer is something more than just copy-and-paste you know... That tutorial was written by newbies, that's why you get errors

Comment: so since you admitted to copy and pasting I'm not going to just give you the answer :)  I will give you a hint though, take a look at your input names and the $_GET index names.  Hopefully that will help

Comment: I didn't copy and paste.

Comment: asked so many times before, please search first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dylan, I highly suggest that you RTM. If you don't understand the undefined index error, it's probably not a good idea to start writing code just yet.

This is thrown on line 7 (like the error states) at `$_GET['login']`. This error was thrown because `login` is not a key found in the `$_GET` array. Therefore, PHP throws the notice. You can add an `isset()` or `!empty()` check to avoid the error, like such:

```
if (!empty($_GET['login']) && $_GET['login'] == "failed" )
```

Answer (score 2):

This notice happens when you're trying to access the element that doesn't exist in array. To check if it does - use `isset()`

```
if (isset($_GET['login']) && $_GET['login'] == "failed") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you run your code at http://localhost/yoursite

If your give the browser the address like this. No error will occur. Because you've assigned to $_GET['login'] the value "failed".

> http://localhsot/yoursite/index.php?login=failed

But if you don't provide "login=failed" in the address

> http://localhost/yoursite/index.php

$_GET['login'] is not set, and php cannot find 'login' index in $_GET array, it throws an error :)

The solution to this is to check if $_GET['login'] is set before checking its value.

```
if ( !empty($_GET['login']) && $_GET['login'] == "failed" )
```

`empty($_GET['login'])` returns true if `$_GET['login']` is NOT set